# Ionic modalController in react package is not found

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am using react with ionic package and I tried to import modalController from '@ionic/react' but an error has eccoured:

`import error: '@ionic/react' does not contain a default export (imported as 'modalController').`.

Did someone used it?
I Would be happy to see some code examples!

Comment: Have you checked the react example in the [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal#usage) on this?

Comment: Yes I have @Phonolog.

Answer (score 0):

The `modalController` is present in `@ionic/core` package but not `@ionic/react`.

You should be importing this statement instead

```
import { modalController } from '@ionic/core';
```

I'm using it to dismiss a Modal in my Ionic-React App.

**Usage**

```
<Button onClick={() => modalController.dismiss()}>Close</Button>
```